# How to handle elements & attributes having same name in xsd while generating pojos using jaxb?

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I have a xsd that contains something like:

```
<xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
    <xs:element ref="HereIsTheProblem"/>
    <xs:element ref="blaBla"/>
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="something" type="xs:string" use="required">
    <xs:annotation/>
  </xs:attribute>
  <xs:attribute name="somethingElse" type="xs:string">
    <xs:annotation/>
  </xs:attribute>
  <xs:attribute name="HereIsTheProblem" type="xs:string">
    <xs:annotation/>
  </xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
```

now when i try to parse the schema using jaxb to generate java classes it fails:

```
[ERROR] Element "{http://something.somemorething.com/etc/}HereIsTheProblem" shows up in more than one properties.
```

how to resolve this without making any modification in the schema?

PS:my jaxb version is 2.1.13

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need to use a binding file indicating jaxB how it should handle this name collision. For example, put something like this in a file named something like bindings.xjb:

```
<jaxb:bindings version="2.1" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc" xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:com.fnf="http://www.fnf.com/xes">
  <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="your schema location here" node="/xs:schema">
    <jaxb:bindings node="//XPath selector">
      <jaxb:property name="HereIsTheProblem2" />
    </jaxb:bindings>
  </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Can't provide you a complete solution without a complete schema

Comment: is it necessary to specify the binding for everything else as well? or only the collisions while jaxb handles rest, please clarify.

Comment: no, only collision is mandatory. You are free to modify the rest as well, but this is not necessary. Basically you must use a binding for everything that prevents jaxb to generate valid classes. The purpose of the bindings is to disamiguate identical names.

Comment: thanks a lot, i'll start looking into it from tomorrow, hopefully will have no further issue regarding this.

Comment: Hum, never had this case to handle, but I am guessing that should take a similar approach, ie, find an XPath selector to one of the ambiguating element and express an alternate name binding so that JaxB can continue. For more info, try googling your error and see the JAXB binding doc.

Answer (score 1):

Also we can modify the XSD as below.

```
    <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence minOccurs="0">
        <xs:element ref="HereIsTheProblem"/>
        <xs:element ref="blaBla"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="something" type="xs:string" use="required">
        <xs:annotation/>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="somethingElse" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation/>
    </xs:attribute>
    <xs:attribute name="HereIsTheProblem" type="xs:string">
        <xs:annotation>
            <xs:appinfo>
                <jaxb:property name="HereIsTheProblemAttr"/>
            </xs:appinfo>
        </xs:annotation>
    </xs:attribute>
</xs:complexType>
```

The main issue is inside the pojo class, if we have the element and the attribute with the same name, it will try to create variables with the same name which is not allowed in simple java principles. So we can define the variable name to be different from one another like above.